# Is $\inf\{d(x,F):x\in E\}$ equal to $\inf\{|x-y|:x\in E,y\in F\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $E,F$ be two non-empty disjoint sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $|\cdot|$ be the Euclidean norm. As introduced in many textbooks on real analysis, we can define the distance $d(E,F)$ between $E$ and $F$ by
$$d(E,F)=\inf\{|x-y|:x\in E,y\in F\}.$$
I'm wondering if we can find $d(E,F)$ by following a **two-step** procedure. Specifically, if we define the distance $d(x,F)$ from $x\in E$ to $F$ by
$$d(x,F)=\inf\{|x-y|:y\in F\},$$
then does
$$\inf\{d(x,F):x\in E\}$$
equal $d(E,F)$? I didn't come across a question regarding double infimums before, and this question right here is too abstract for me. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

//////////////////////////

**Update:** I got something!!! Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. If we could verify the following two assertions (1) and (2), then the two infimums in the title would agree!!!

(1) $\forall x\in E$, $d(E,F)-\epsilon<d(x,F)$.

(2) $\exists x\in E$ s.t. $d(E,F)+\epsilon>d(x,F)$.

Assertion (2) can be easily verified by taking $(x,y_0)\in E\times F$ with $d(E,F)+\epsilon>|x-y_0|$ and noting that
$$|x-y_0|\geq\inf\{|x-y|:y\in F\}=d(x,F).$$
Now it remains to show that assertion (1) is true.

Comment: Yes, $\inf_i \inf_j a_{ij}$ is same as $\inf_{i,j} a_{ij}$.

Comment: That seems plausible, but what's your point, please?

Comment: As a special case of the equation I wrote it follows that the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: You don't need to know even the definition of a metric to answer this question. It is question about infima of sets of real numbers.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Give me some time to figure it out.

Comment: You might be interested in Hausdorff distance between two sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

Answer (score 1):

I’m just gonna show the assertion. 
Indeed, $d(x,F)\geq d(E,F)$, since $x\in E$. 
Then let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $d(x,F)\geq d(E,F)>d(E,F)-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank God! I successfully verified assertion (1)!!! Fix $x_0\in E$. Now observe that
$$d(E,F)=\inf(\bigcup_{x\in E}\{|x-y|:y\in F\})\leq\inf\{|x_0-y|:y\in F\}=d(x_0,F).$$
Assertion (1) then follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same and you don't have to go so much into the definition of distances to see that. You simply have to show that for a family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$ you have
$$\inf_{i \in I} (\inf(A_i)) = \inf \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right).$$